# Is there any frameworks for JSP like Primefaces?

Tags: jsp

Primefaces is very useful and easy to learn UI for JSF. I prefer JSP for web development and I need a good looking and easy to learn framework. I liked ExtJS but it is not free and I can't afford it. My applications based on data tables. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't find a substitute as well integrated as Primefaces for programming rich UI with JSP.

Primefaces, which relies on JSF, is event oriented and strongly coupled to the UI which helps to provide rich widgets like datatables.

JSP is request oriented and I'm not aware of rich taglibs.

The best thing I can advise you would be to work with jQuery or other javascript framework.

For your information jQuery has a datatable plugin, check out http://www.datatables.net/

**UPDATE**

I almost forgot, you can also have a look to [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/) which helps on building highly *ajaxified* application in Java.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. On the other hand, ExtJS is a js framework as well. Using a js framework makes more sense.

Comment: Updated, just added a reference to DWR which you could find helpful to integrate your client side code with your java code.